# Convert an integer into a datetime object

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, integer

How do I convert an entire column in a data frame from an integer class into a date time object?

e.g. 2014 into a date time object 01-01-2014

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with each integer:

```
int = 2014
import datetime

converted = datetime.datetime(int, 1, 1)
return converted
```

If you have a table, use the `for` loop as shown below:

```
table = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2021]
converted = []
import datetime

for year in table:
    converted.append(datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1))
return converted
```

In this latter case, you will get back a list with the converted values being in the order of the original values.

Comment: Since the OP has a DataFrame (pandas I presume), you would not use a loop but `pd.to_datetime`, with `unit='Y'`